# Send mail using Redemption (RDO)

Tags: c#, email, rdo

I am using Redemption (`RDO`) to send an e-mail. The mailing works just fine, but when in Outlook the mail is received, the yellow envelope keeps closed. Normally you click on an unopened e-mail and then the icon change from a yellow closed envelope to a white opened envelope. When I send an e-mail using `RDO` the envelope stays yellow and closed.

How can I suppress that the envelope goes open?

Here is my code:

```
RDOSessionClass rdoSession = new RDOSessionClass();
rdoSession.LogonExchangeMailbox("username", "server");

// Create mail object and send mail
RDOMailClass m = (RDOMailClass)rdoSession.GetSharedDefaultFolder("user", rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items.Add("IPM.Mail");
m.Recipients.Add(_mail.Recipient);
m.Recipients.ResolveAll(null, null);
m.Subject = _mail.Subject;
m.Body = _mail.Body;
m.SenderEmailAddress = "email@address.domain";
m.Send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. In my code I've used `IPM.Mail`, which doesn't exists. It has to be `IPM.Note`. Now it is working just fine.